# How to add attribute for RRP in frontend?

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, custom-attributes

In Magento 2.1 CE, luma theme, I'm trying to add a product attribute called "RRP" (Recommended Retail Price) and like to display it on the frontend product page and in catalog near the other prices. (Existing MSRP function isn't appropriate because i don't use MAP.)

I've added an price-attribute called "RRP" in backend, and there it's visible. In frontend, it's shown in "more information"-tab, but i like to show it near the other prices.

I've tried to call it in "vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml" with following code:

`<?php echo $_product->getRrp(); ?>`

but it's not visible.

Is this the right file and the right code to call the attribute? Or do i have to add something other to call the attribute in frontend?

But price is shown with 4 decimals, for example 10.0000 instead 10.00, and without currency symbol.

code i've used to show the attribute value:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getRrp(), 'rrp') ?>
```

to show attribute label also, i've tried following code, but this doesn't work:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getRrp(), 'rrp'); $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rrp')->getStoreLabel() ?>
```

How i could add global currency format to the attribute?
And how i could add the attribute label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Show Custom Attribute in product list page you can used following code,

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getRrp(), 'rrp') ?>
```

Note : Make sure attribute option is visible for product listing page from admin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
Do you know how to add global price format to the attribute also?

Comment: If above answer help you, please accept. So it will help other in community. And if you required further help you can ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow this attribute in attribute setting "Show in product list page" to "yes" in attribute setting.